# How to apply a Javascript animation function to multiple images in for loop?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, animation, requestanimationframe

I am trying to apply animation to all of the images created in a for loop without manually doing it, but none of the images created in the for loop are showing any animation, I have tried in multiple ways such as using forEach and a regular for loop paired with querySelectorAll. When I tried to fix my problem with those methods, it either only affected the first image from the for loop or nothing happened at all.

**Essentially, what I want is to make it so the 10 images created prior in a for loop can have the same animation as the first image that is being animated across the screen.** I also want the other images created to have the same functionality as the first image, when the image is clicked, the click counter should also work similar to that of the first image sliding across the screen. Please help.

Full code is linked **here:** **https://code.sololearn.com/Wwdw59oenFqB**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <style>
        body {
        zoom: 25%
        }
          .circle {
            display: block;
            background: black;
            border-radius: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;

            background: radial-gradient(circle at center,#31f541, #000);
          }
          .container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
          }
          .circle-image{
              z-index: 2;
              position: absolute;
              margin-left: 50%;
              margin-top: 50vh;
              border-radius: 50%;
          }

      </style>
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="container">
          <img id = "firstImage" style = "height: 1000px; width: 1000px;" onclick = "change(); clickCounter(); animate(); saveData();"class="circle-image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAIQAWQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAIDBAUBB//EADsQAAIBAwMCAwYFAgMJAQAAAAECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRIlJhcYGRFDJCofDB0SMzsRUkJVNiY5Ki4Qf/xAAYAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMABP/EAB8RAAMBAAMBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAABAhEDEiExQTJRBP/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AMAM1V1S7/BRI7ZwzbeKu45rJ8VRFtIaRR/lOrfTp/Wov4VlbSLlpeRXEWVkBPcHgj6VaAyOtCen3BghWd2AJ5OWxgVonUHaPzbJtxUZaPggj1GKDrqtKPj1+G4qmuiM9axG1SdUG4AEruxVaLVLozZ39DgCpP/olGXBRtahothqSBL+yguF/7iA4+vah+f8A/N/DLsXNk8WeoSdwPtmtE6pdkP5YDBf3NUbvU7gkrdzbe+wcAf3p5503iA+F/pUHhjwrpkgaHTo55F7zs0gH0JxRtoU4ng9hVVF4AVcAfSgvfbsm4SqW9G/oaK/CqkWAdujMcU+6zVCUhLHmpcH1qKOpOaJIG8dqbdwLPaTQuMq6EGp8YNcdcxsM4yDWCeXRPcQXgtmupI4W5ymDj55HFb9m8VsuLbALctkdfjxWdqls5vvNtwFyMPj9WK09KsAwUyE4PAPpUq98R0Ov0iuLnN2gYjocE9M1HbTqszO54RSTiu3NiDHc7mDski7cfOo9MtPPvnhlUgPKvX3ev9q5HDTKzXhr2MiGEhc9SRnqarXkUbuznIk7N3rXhtE8+XB9lD2p0+ng+2EIJHGarxy5+i1WglaQXV9cbZUIWMgt64+VemafAsFtFEgACqKGNN0qddQa4nUhSu0DPB+NFqj2QDjoOa6ZJc1biLUbdqmyPU1ViOKmzTkDHA4Ga48SsjL0yKcoPNdHUUAHmupXRsrya3cMzK2FA70IeJ/EusW9yIILk28SqMBAP3Neh+M9OX8WLkthnXBz2NCH+yYtRn/4gkm7oHU/mFQhqK9L52nwl8K6vNemfbLK6Ryqf8XBYgjvgAdc0eaZZCeRnTjnP2/goN0RItLuzBa2vkRTsAGkPJx3JPWj4XDWsAW2IkZ8rgdc0z6uu2eDTNJYeVa5431KPX7iOzvWtbVZHUGOEOTtyO5GcsPXgetek+E9cuNS0GC61PaH3FPMRSAceorC1DwNpV7OLt1ktJGbdJEBwW+o4z8KItJtQtumnxRiOziGAPe+JprqanJFlNPWbMU4klEanOPh2q8eO/SqOmWzRK5Yg4OF+VXwD6fOtxziEt6yRDg89q7vH8NR9+mfia7g+g/n1qghX4yfnSGO9RhwwDDvTlGfpWFMbxXDDNpjeavI/KQO9BlisEMi7trrnoq5A+db3ja8LAWiSez+oLQXFJJbkYJEe7C8dT6motrsWlPqE2sSabPYiC6iKqDlHjO0q3qDzS8FarZQXRN2GknyUSSTrt7cUNpq7bvbQSLWlFqEUv8AlW5LDoSKsuSTZSWHot7Lp8lvJJIPabngHJrNtC8k26EmODoT61l6bNcTAMYyvoWrYtYzI4cggDpkYzU7qfqNM1+hHHGqxgL0ru3HOeKjtiTGuSOBTyeRnGMVReol8Ywjnkc0tx9B9qcRwO2TioMt7p/asYz9Mm8+zjcd1Bq2X2qze6M1i+FpRJYKpPKjH2OK17s4tpCOu04x64oaBnmusXgudQn5w+7GCTUBiDRqrjjHf1qtLJiVi8gD5POMU+zuvOcxSHcw5GBg8VCVp0PxF+w8PpJ5bkNtY4HpRdpWiWykx42uvH7VR0GfMTJIApbBA900QW0pkLyKMeYQTnscAH/SqriWk3yMSafbwPhjuOeFNTuAH2oAcdsVn36+RG8itiVuASc/am2NxOx/3m4xH37E/WtfHgZts27KVSWQMSR1PYVZHtcYx061QspCzHy1UQjoB1Pxq7uGfX4UY/kTk/oW0c7qZlvQU9mH6T0Hao/Z+H/lTAAfwzd+WJkJ43ZHyOP7UTRXcTqVJ615rbX5t5GKH8wq+mtyAdeaTsHB+qWUSXM8DMn5iVB7g+lC/leRqkaISuX5FFkcqXUnmMhLMv5sftWPrlt+GniuFH6wf3pV4U+o39PnARsDlQCKJLOU+WFTvk5+FClo+xQ6+7RBplyrxxjncw+wrokjSI/Flv59pboz4BuE/YE0zTIwqqXVmPQNU2vXURezhboXLf8AqamsvL/JHGGOeppOZoeE0bemwiKIscgsc+1U7MMhTw1MUlY1PcDmm7lkYnjdQn4CvWPCnII4GccCltP8amiR4c7/AGhjAIqT8RH/ANVE2HiUIwcjrU+4AVDHx0p7da5ygS6BeQeQIyR5oOMN0xT/ABLJbyQJAux5GOSVbO2hV8gcVbsruNxtc4ZabfDYX4lYSAxkHC+yDWxps8i7AwXaFOD9qyIYDv3BsjpkelXYUdME42AYqiYrG6neb9Ri3jlDkEfGiLSbgOVXZtLHAz3rFg038TMHcDg8UV6ZB/iKoHC0v1+h3zw1BwowR8eaYVjyGxjmpSVK8fSoZVLDk8+oqgguMn0x9qZti979/wD5UYk8olXBYetP/FL6j7GgE8pj0qUD8pqOazlTOUOMelejDT4wv5ail0uJ/wBPwxS9A6eayo3OQRUJgdIwQpJIzmvRJdAifkqMH4VFF4e8sso8t0I9jd1X4fGlcMZVgBtf3Vn5cm0lCeR8KJLOeaeZCkDbCc4PpW7e+GYruzeJAqyFPZOOAan0eNR5azKsMxGDGR3HBx602NIGpsWnJOm1WiIY84AohtYliVuPbJ5NPCqFXaOi8/OuIecY6E5opf6Bseo9nA64610bcZPYenNNBw23BIHHSub8MQM/amARTRK+SwBPc5HpUP4KP3D9hVmTjlenyrm0f82sYqsxCkjt/enI29sN6fz/AFpUqBjp/Lk9hxXUUEtSpVjD04OMnjpUnBxkClSogOljj5iuRHJI90ZFcpVjDixJJPf+tMYYVcfqzmlSrBHSLjjPcD7ml+HT1NKlWCf/2Q==">
          <img id = "secondImage" style = "height: 1000px; width: 1000px;" onclick = "animate();"class="circle-image" src="https://en.meming.world/images/en/thumb/e/e2/Crying_Cat_screaming.jpg/300px-Crying_Cat_screaming.jpg">
          <p style = "transform: scale(10, 10);"id = "clicker">Kitten has been pat: <a id="clickCounter">0</a> times in <a id = "timeCounter">0</a> seconds</p>
          <figure class="circle"></figure>

      </div>
      <button onclick = "saveData();"id = "saveButton">Load progress</button>
  <script>
const cats = [];
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,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");
        img.className = "catSwarm"
        img.addEventListener('click', function handleClick(event) {
        change(); clickCounter();


});
img.addEventListener('load', function handleClick(event) {

    })

        document.body.appendChild(img);
        cats.push(img)

}

      let clicks = 0;
function clickCounter() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clickCounter").innerHTML = clicks;
  if (clicks != 10) {

  }
  else {
      alert("Kitten has been pet 10 times")
  }
};
let time = 0;

function timeCounter() {
    time+=1
    document.getElementById("timeCounter").innerHTML = time;
    setTimeout(timeCounter, 1000)
    if(time != 10) {

    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function() {
        alert ("Kitten has been pet " + clicks + " times in " + time + " seconds" + " with a whopping pats per second rate of " + clicks/time + "!")
    }, 10);
}}
timeCounter();

      function change() {
          if(document.getElementById("firstImage").style.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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") {
              document.getElementById("firstImage").src = "https://en.meming.world/images/en/thumb/e/e2/Crying_Cat_screaming.jpg/300px-Crying_Cat_screaming.jpg";
          }
          else {document.getElementById("firstImage").style.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBwgHBgkIBwgKCgkLDRYPDQwMDRsUFRAWIB0iIiAdHx8kKDQsJCYxJx8fLT0tMTU3Ojo6Iys/RD84QzQ5OjcBCgoKDQwNGg8PGjclHyU3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3Nzc3N//AABEIAIQAWQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAABBQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAIDBAUBB//EADsQAAIBAwMCAwYFAgMJAQAAAAECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRIlJhcYGRFDJCofDB0SMzsRUkJVNiY5Ki4Qf/xAAYAQADAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMABP/EAB8RAAMBAAMBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAABAhEDEiExQTJRBP/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8AMAM1V1S7/BRI7ZwzbeKu45rJ8VRFtIaRR/lOrfTp/Wov4VlbSLlpeRXEWVkBPcHgj6VaAyOtCen3BghWd2AJ5OWxgVonUHaPzbJtxUZaPggj1GKDrqtKPj1+G4qmuiM9axG1SdUG4AEruxVaLVLozZ39DgCpP/olGXBRtahothqSBL+yguF/7iA4+vah+f8A/N/DLsXNk8WeoSdwPtmtE6pdkP5YDBf3NUbvU7gkrdzbe+wcAf3p5503iA+F/pUHhjwrpkgaHTo55F7zs0gH0JxRtoU4ng9hVVF4AVcAfSgvfbsm4SqW9G/oaK/CqkWAdujMcU+6zVCUhLHmpcH1qKOpOaJIG8dqbdwLPaTQuMq6EGp8YNcdcxsM4yDWCeXRPcQXgtmupI4W5ymDj55HFb9m8VsuLbALctkdfjxWdqls5vvNtwFyMPj9WK09KsAwUyE4PAPpUq98R0Ov0iuLnN2gYjocE9M1HbTqszO54RSTiu3NiDHc7mDski7cfOo9MtPPvnhlUgPKvX3ev9q5HDTKzXhr2MiGEhc9SRnqarXkUbuznIk7N3rXhtE8+XB9lD2p0+ng+2EIJHGarxy5+i1WglaQXV9cbZUIWMgt64+VemafAsFtFEgACqKGNN0qddQa4nUhSu0DPB+NFqj2QDjoOa6ZJc1biLUbdqmyPU1ViOKmzTkDHA4Ga48SsjL0yKcoPNdHUUAHmupXRsrya3cMzK2FA70IeJ/EusW9yIILk28SqMBAP3Neh+M9OX8WLkthnXBz2NCH+yYtRn/4gkm7oHU/mFQhqK9L52nwl8K6vNemfbLK6Ryqf8XBYgjvgAdc0eaZZCeRnTjnP2/goN0RItLuzBa2vkRTsAGkPJx3JPWj4XDWsAW2IkZ8rgdc0z6uu2eDTNJYeVa5431KPX7iOzvWtbVZHUGOEOTtyO5GcsPXgetek+E9cuNS0GC61PaH3FPMRSAceorC1DwNpV7OLt1ktJGbdJEBwW+o4z8KItJtQtumnxRiOziGAPe+JprqanJFlNPWbMU4klEanOPh2q8eO/SqOmWzRK5Yg4OF+VXwD6fOtxziEt6yRDg89q7vH8NR9+mfia7g+g/n1qghX4yfnSGO9RhwwDDvTlGfpWFMbxXDDNpjeavI/KQO9BlisEMi7trrnoq5A+db3ja8LAWiSez+oLQXFJJbkYJEe7C8dT6motrsWlPqE2sSabPYiC6iKqDlHjO0q3qDzS8FarZQXRN2GknyUSSTrt7cUNpq7bvbQSLWlFqEUv8AlW5LDoSKsuSTZSWHot7Lp8lvJJIPabngHJrNtC8k26EmODoT61l6bNcTAMYyvoWrYtYzI4cggDpkYzU7qfqNM1+hHHGqxgL0ru3HOeKjtiTGuSOBTyeRnGMVReol8Ywjnkc0tx9B9qcRwO2TioMt7p/asYz9Mm8+zjcd1Bq2X2qze6M1i+FpRJYKpPKjH2OK17s4tpCOu04x64oaBnmusXgudQn5w+7GCTUBiDRqrjjHf1qtLJiVi8gD5POMU+zuvOcxSHcw5GBg8VCVp0PxF+w8PpJ5bkNtY4HpRdpWiWykx42uvH7VR0GfMTJIApbBA900QW0pkLyKMeYQTnscAH/SqriWk3yMSafbwPhjuOeFNTuAH2oAcdsVn36+RG8itiVuASc/am2NxOx/3m4xH37E/WtfHgZts27KVSWQMSR1PYVZHtcYx061QspCzHy1UQjoB1Pxq7uGfX4UY/kTk/oW0c7qZlvQU9mH6T0Hao/Z+H/lTAAfwzd+WJkJ43ZHyOP7UTRXcTqVJ615rbX5t5GKH8wq+mtyAdeaTsHB+qWUSXM8DMn5iVB7g+lC/leRqkaISuX5FFkcqXUnmMhLMv5sftWPrlt+GniuFH6wf3pV4U+o39PnARsDlQCKJLOU+WFTvk5+FClo+xQ6+7RBplyrxxjncw+wrokjSI/Flv59pboz4BuE/YE0zTIwqqXVmPQNU2vXURezhboXLf8AqamsvL/JHGGOeppOZoeE0bemwiKIscgsc+1U7MMhTw1MUlY1PcDmm7lkYnjdQn4CvWPCnII4GccCltP8amiR4c7/AGhjAIqT8RH/ANVE2HiUIwcjrU+4AVDHx0p7da5ygS6BeQeQIyR5oOMN0xT/ABLJbyQJAux5GOSVbO2hV8gcVbsruNxtc4ZabfDYX4lYSAxkHC+yDWxps8i7AwXaFOD9qyIYDv3BsjpkelXYUdME42AYqiYrG6neb9Ri3jlDkEfGiLSbgOVXZtLHAz3rFg038TMHcDg8UV6ZB/iKoHC0v1+h3zw1BwowR8eaYVjyGxjmpSVK8fSoZVLDk8+oqgguMn0x9qZti979/wD5UYk8olXBYetP/FL6j7GgE8pj0qUD8pqOazlTOUOMelejDT4wv5ail0uJ/wBPwxS9A6eayo3OQRUJgdIwQpJIzmvRJdAifkqMH4VFF4e8sso8t0I9jd1X4fGlcMZVgBtf3Vn5cm0lCeR8KJLOeaeZCkDbCc4PpW7e+GYruzeJAqyFPZOOAan0eNR5azKsMxGDGR3HBx602NIGpsWnJOm1WiIY84AohtYliVuPbJ5NPCqFXaOi8/OuIecY6E5opf6Bseo9nA64610bcZPYenNNBw23BIHHSub8MQM/amARTRK+SwBPc5HpUP4KP3D9hVmTjlenyrm0f82sYqsxCkjt/enI29sN6fz/AFpUqBjp/Lk9hxXUUEtSpVjD04OMnjpUnBxkClSogOljj5iuRHJI90ZFcpVjDixJJPf+tMYYVcfqzmlSrBHSLjjPcD7ml+HT1NKlWCf/2Q=="> {

          }
      }}
      function saveData() {

  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.querySelector("p").innerText = "Kitten has been pat: " + localStorage.clickcount + " times in " + time + " seconds";
  }

      }
const fps = 25;

let image = document.querySelector("img");
let angle = Math.PI / 2;
//store the previous time the animate function last fired
let prevTimeArg;

function animate(currentTimeParam){


    if (prevTimeArg != null) {
        angle += (currentTimeParam - prevTimeArg) * 0.004;
    }
    // Setting the previous time to the time the function currently fires
    prevTimeArg = currentTimeParam ;
    image.style.top = (Math.tan(angle) * 150) + "px";
    image.style.left = (Math.tan(angle) * 150) + "px";
    image.style.height = (Math.cos(angle) * 1000) + "px";
    image.style.width = (Math.cos(angle) * 1000) + "px";


setTimeout(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(currentTime => animate(currentTime));
}, 0 / fps)}

    for (i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }



  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Why is the code the same as in the previous one. The idea was you update the code and ask the new question for the missing bit

Comment: Why is your `load` `.addEventListener` outside the loop? Also, `data:` images trigger their `load` event almost instantly. You'd need to set the `load` listener before you set the `src` attribute.